# NullExceptionError when trying to load image from Resources

Tags: c#, string, image, visual-studio, resources

I have my resources embedded in the system, the string I search for them with matches the name of the image yet I still get a ArgumentNullException... How come?

```
    //Check if currencies are chosen
    private void Action()
    {
        label1.Text = null;
        //Checks if items are selected then what currencies are chosen
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            label1.Text = "Please select currencies";
        }
        else
        {
        LB1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        LB2 = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Conversion();
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(LB1) as Image;
        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(LB2) as Image;
    }
```

[Picture of Resource images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M47MP.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does `SelectedItem.ToString()` return the result you were expecting? I think you probably want `SelectedValue` instead.

Comment: The ToString method seems to be working fine, I tested it and it returns the correct value, so when I press AUD to returns a string AUD.. It's a really strange error

Answer (score 1):

You've got a small logic flaw. You are setting variables inside an `if` condition but using them outside, even if the `if` condition doesn't execute.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    label1.Text = "Please select currencies";
}
else
{
    LB1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();  //Doesn't always run
    LB2 = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Conversion();
}
//Always runs
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(LB1) as Image;
pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(LB2) as Image;
```

You should probably change it to something more like this:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    label1.Text = "Please select currencies";
}
else
{
    LB1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    LB2 = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Conversion();
    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(LB1) as Image;
    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(LB2) as Image;        }
}
```

Or better yet, use a [guard](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1149121&seqNum=11), and use local variables, so that the compiler will catch this sort of flaw in the future:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    label1.Text = "Please select currencies";
    return;
}
var lb1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
var lb2 = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
Conversion(lb1, lb2);
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(lb2) as Image;
pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(lb2) as Image;
```